# pytest: environment variable to specify pytest.ini location

Tags: python, docker, pytest, pytest-django

How can I set an environment variable with the location of the `pytest.ini`, `tox.ini` or `setup.cfg` for running `pytest` by default?

I created a docker container with a volume pointing to my project directory, so every change I make is also visible inside the docker container. The problem is that I have a `pytest.ini` file on my project root which won't apply to the docker container.

So I want to set an environment variable inside the docker container to specify where to look for the pytest configuration. Does anyone have any idea how could I do that?

Comment: Why can't you just run pytest from the volume containing your project?

Comment: because the volume also has the `pytest.ini` I have on my project root. I would have to run it with `pytest -c /location/of/new/pytest.ini`

Comment: What `pytest.ini` file do you want to use when running `pytest` inside the container, the one in your project directory or another one?  If another one, you should make that clearer in the question.

Comment: The documentation does not show using a variable for this. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to do that. You can use a different pytest configuration using `pytest -c` but `tox.ini` and `setup.cfg` must reside in the top-level directory of your package, next to `setup.py`.